# Swift 5 TableView found nil inside ViewController when i try to reloaddate

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview, swift5

i am fetching the data from and API endpoint and on the first fetch the tableview is working.

But when i am changing the API url the fetch still works but for the tableview the xcode is throwing the "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value" error message."

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
   
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var listOfRecipes = [RecipeDetail]()
    {
        didSet {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData() --->> Here i get the nil error
            }
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
        callApi()
        
    }
    
    func callApi() {
        print("------------------- API -------------------")
        print(ApiSettings.instance.apiEndpoint)
        //self.listOfRecipes.removeAll()
        let recipeRequest = RecipeRequest(url: ApiSettings.instance.apiEndpoint)
        recipeRequest.getData{  result in
            switch result {
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                case .success(let recipes):
                    self.listOfRecipes = recipes
            }
        }
    }
  
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return listOfRecipes.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        let recipe = listOfRecipes[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = recipe.title
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = recipe.slug
        return cell
    }
}
```

I also tried to remove all connections from the tableview also on the storyboard and add them again, also delegate and datasource, but it is still not working. The first load works perfectly but after the app crashes.

I also checked the  listOfRecipes didSet, and inside it the array has the new values from the second API query.

Anyone maybe any suggestion? thanks!

Comment: I removed my earlier comment because you answer it near the end of your question.  However, on what line of code do you get the fatal error unwrapping nil?

Comment: sry, i extended my description.

But here on the api change:

var listOfRecipes = [RecipeDetail]()
    {
        didSet {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData() --->> Here i get the nil error
            }
        }
    }

Comment: The only optional value I see in your `didSet` is for `tableView`, which is an implicitly unwrapped optional, so it must be the thing that is `nil`.   I don't see where you are setting it (perhaps externally to `ViewController`?), but I would normally expect to find it in `viewDidLoad`.  What's weird is that you're setting its `delegate` and `dataSource` in `viewDidLoad`.  If it were `nil`, I would expect you to get the error there first.

Comment: It looks like someone else found the answer for you.  I'm glad it worked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reloading the table view in a property observer is not a good practice. Most likely the error occurs because the table view outlet isn’t connected yet when the observer is called the first time.

Reload it in the API call.

```
var listOfRecipes = [RecipeDetail]()


func callApi() {
    print("------------------- API -------------------")
    print(ApiSettings.instance.apiEndpoint)
    //self.listOfRecipes.removeAll()
    let recipeRequest = RecipeRequest(url: ApiSettings.instance.apiEndpoint)
    recipeRequest.getData{  result in
        switch result {
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            case .success(let recipes):
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                   self.listOfRecipes = recipes
                   self.tableView.reloadData() 
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggest, but I have the same error, just now inside the main async

```         case .success(let recipes):
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                   self.listOfRecipes = recipes
                   self.tableView.reloadData()   --> Now i get here the nil error
                }
```

on the storyboard i also checked the tableview and the datasource and delegate is the ViewController....

Comment: Then the outlet is not connected properly and/or your way to instantiate the controller is wrong.

Comment: but then why it is working on the first load? it is fetching everything from the callApi func.

and the outlet is also connected.

Comment: You were right, your solution is working! My problem caused the SideMenu. 

thanks for your help!